# Private key not used in a signature scheme

Tags: signature, keys

I'm trying to understand the following signature scheme (Camenisch-Lysanskaya):

**Key generation:**
$n = pq$ special RSA modulus, $a, b, c \in QR_n$. $PK = (n, a, b, c), SK = p$.

**Signing algorithm:**

- $m$ message.
- $e$ random prime number (with some for this question unimportant length restriction).
- $s$ random number with very big length (unimportant for my question).
- Compute $v^e \equiv a^m b^s c \bmod n$. Output $(e,s,v)$.

**Verification algorithm:** Check that $v^e \equiv a^m b^s c \bmod n$ and check the length restriction of $e$.

---

I don't see why this is a valid signing algorithm. The secret key is not used for signing (or calculating $e$ or $s$). So everyone could make a signature like this and not just the one who created the public key.

Edit: If I understand it right, it's all about the hard computation of a $v$ and $e$ if you just have $a^m b^s c$. But how does it help there to know the factorization of $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Compute $v^e \equiv a^m b^s c \pmod n$. Output $(e,s,v)$.

This should perhaps read:

- *Solve* $v^e \equiv a^m b^s c \pmod n$ for $v$.  Output $(e,s,v)$.

If you can solve $v^e \equiv u \pmod n$ for $v$ without using $p$ in general, you have found a major breakthrough in cryptanalysis!

Comment: Yes that is, what I also read. But how does it help for the calculation to know the factorization of $n$?

Comment: Or the other way around: why can I solve the factorization problem if I would have found some $e, v$ to a given $u, n$ s.t. $v^e \equiv u \bmod n$?

Comment: How does knowing the factorization of $n$ help to find $v$?  If you know $p$ and $q$ so that $n = pq$, you can compute $\lambda(n) = \operatorname{lcm}(p - 1, q - 1)$ and solve $e d \equiv 1 \pmod{\lambda(n)}$ for $d$ and compute $v \equiv (a^m b^s c)^d \pmod n$ as in RSA.  $$$$  How does finding $v$ help to find the factorization of $n$?  We don't know, except in the cases of even exponents, since knowing two distinct square roots $y$ and $y'$ of a common square $x\equiv y^2\equiv (y')^2\pmod n$ so that $(y+y')(y-y')=kn$ for some $k$ reveals the factorization of $n$ by $\gcd(n, y \pm y')$.

Comment: From a cursory glance, the security of this system seems to rely on the RSA problem, not directly on factorization.  The RSA problem—inverting $x^e \bmod n$ for uniform random $x$ and appropriate choice of $e$—is certainly not _harder_ than factoring, but it may be easier.